# domain name - Count number of characters except TLDs

Tags: jquery, regex

I need domain name counting of characters and fill input hidden.

domain name: google.com
count google only
count value = 5
do not count TLDs - .com

Where is the problem -  it is not working.

```js
$('#domain').keyup(updateInputs);
$('#domain').keydown(updateInputs);
$('#domain').trigger('keyup');

function updateInputs() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $('#count').val($(this).val().replace(/(?=\.).*/).length);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" class="domain" value="google.com">
<input type="text" name="count" id="count" class="count" value="">
```

```js
$('#domain').keyup(updateInputs);
$('#domain').keydown(updateInputs);
$('#domain').trigger('keyup');



function updateInputs() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    var onedot = new RegExp('(?=\.).*');
    var counter = $(this).val().match(onedot).length;
    $('#count').prop('value', counter);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" class="domain" value="google.com">
<input type="text" name="count" id="count" class="count" value="">
```

Comment: lenght is spelled wrong in the second example

Comment: What about `.co.uk` or `.com.cn`

Comment: Also it is .val(...) not .text(....) in the first example

Comment: I will use only few LTDs, not all

Comment: I created two snippets and fixed your typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the replace by string

```js
$('#domain')
  .on("input",updateInputs)
  .trigger('input');

function updateInputs() {
    $('#count').val(
      $(this).val().replace(/(?=\.).*/,"").length || ""
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" class="domain" value="google.com">
<input type="text" name="count" id="count" class="count" value="">
```

Comment: Its working like a charm. :-)